# Google Experiment shows 0 conversions but goal has plenty

Tags: analytics, google-experiments

I have a website with a booking system on another domain
The cross domain tracking is working fine.

I have set up a goal called "Booking system entered" which successfully tracks visitors hitting the first step in the booking system.

In my new Experiment i have used this goal for conversions. But even though i know there has been several conversions, meaning people going from version A or version B in my experiment to the booking system, the experiment keeps saying 0 conversions. The number of views is correct. But conversions are not counted at all?

The goal destination ("Begins with") is set up with the first part of the URL of the booking system.

The tracking codes on both domains have the following code added (with their domain):

```
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'DOMAIN NAME HERE'])
```

And the experiment code has:

```
_udn = "DOMAIN NAME HERE";
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the details, I would say that you should check to see that the Google Analytics tracking code is still on the site, where the goals happen.

Also make sure that the cookie domain, path and domain hash in the experiment code is the SAME as the Google Analytics tracking code. That should solve your problems.